# Gradle : Cannot add task ‘:helloFromBuild1′ as a task with that name already exists

Tags: gradle

Gradle gives the below error in terminal.

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Cannot add task ':helloFromBuild1' as a task with that name already exists.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: you need to provide more context to solve this. how does your build script looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Task name collision may result from improperly importing files. For a better explanation see this article [Gradle : Cannot add task ‘:helloFromBuild1’ as a task with that name already exists.](https://compsciworld.wordpress.com/2015/06/13/gradle-cannot-add-task-hellofrombuild1-as-a-task-with-that-name-already-exists/).

An very small excerpt from the solution in the above mentioned link is below:

> Solution :
>
> If you want to import task of both build_1.gradle and build_2.gradle
> in build_3.gradle then in a case like above , you can do it only by
> importing build_2.gradle in build_3.gradle, since tasks of
> build_1.gradle are already included in build_2.gradle.

Comment: Just linking to your own library (or utility) is not a good answer. Linking to it, explaining why it solves the problem, providing code using it to do so and disclaiming makes for a better answer. See: [How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/)